# (EEVEE) The whole scene goes white when I bake indirect lighting. What could be causing this?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, baking, lighting, lightprobe

[image]I´m pretty new to Blender, and I had always used Cycles to render everything up until now. I have a scene, that was previously set up for cycles, and I´m trying to bake the lighting in eevee, but when I do the whole scene becomes this white glow with infinite intensity (just inside of the probe). I tried hiding literally every object in the scene, disabling all world nodes, and even mounting the whole scene again on  another project, and I can´t get it to work out. Also, I noticed that before I baked there was a reflection of a huge light (that shouldn´t exist) on a reflective floor I had around.
Any ideas? Cause I all out.
[image]

Comment: are you sure you don't have a light that is hidden but activated for render?

Comment: Pretty sure, yeah. I´d upload the blend file but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Go here - https://blend-exchange.com/ - copy and paste in the URL of this question, upload your file, tick the boxes, copy the link they give you and paste it in to your question.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Will do.

Comment: Well... I´ve been trying to upload it for hours and it just won´t. Seems luck ain´t on my side this week.

Comment: You clicked the button that says "upload", right? Also, it wont work with files over 50mb.

Comment: Yeah, and then I left it for an hour and it was about 20% in and not even moving at all. It´s 200 mb and my internet is pretty good, so it´s pretty weird. Still, I think I´ve found the source of the issue. The grass I have on my scene seems to be the cause of the huge light blooming everywhere, somehow. It´s made from hair particles and it has a very simple material, but maybe something weird happened when I switched to eevee.

Comment: Can´t I just upload it to drive and post the link here?

Comment: Done, I think. I just deleted everything except the grass and a few lights I had around. Thanks for the help, btw :)

Comment: Oh, and by done I mean the upload, not the issue xD